# Most Flexible Photo Gallery Plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, images, gallery

What is the most flexible photo gallery plugin available on WordPress?

By flexible, I mean a plugin that can:

- create galleries per folder / event
- display / generate thumbnails per size I want (it would be good to have an API/function for this)
- display the most recent gallery from either certain event or all photos uploaded.

Is there any? Or something close to this?

Comment: What is a folder and what is a event? Just asking because I think that folders and events is nothing that wordpress has in core.

Comment: how should I say? per category? or 1 event = several photos or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most full featured one I've found is NextGEN gallery. It even has add-ons for specific functionality beyond what's built in.

Answer (score 2):

FLAGallery - Very good way to display the gallery - has all the options of NextGEN

some screenshots : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flash-album-gallery/screenshots/

See it in action on some blog : 
http://abzyy.com/?p=527

some skins :
http://www.flash-photogallery.com/3d-cube-grand-flagallery-skin.html

Hope that helps (:

Answer (score 1):

PhotoSmash is quite flexible also. Some features:

- create unlimited galleries and show multiple galleries on a post or page
- extensive shortcode options
- set multiple sizes of images to be created
- resize images (unfortunately, doesn't have the javascript cropping function of NextGEN)
- adds your uploaded images as WP Attachments so you can also use the standard WP gallery functions
- allow site visitors to upload to galleries
- create custom fields
- create custom forms
- create custom layouts
- show tag, recent, highest rated, random, and contributor (virtual) galleries
- widget for displaying mini galleries in sidebar
- widget for Photo Tag Cloud
- with PS Extend, can create new Posts on image uploads
- and has its own iPhone App

On WordPress:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/